# spring security - user have multiple roles for multiple departments. - how to specify the role?

Tags: spring, security, role

I have tables for authentication as below,

employee

---

id_employee, username, password ...

---

1, John, woefijlsdkjfu230rdfrfj
2, Peter, sdlautoerwjgosj120943820

---

---

employee_department

---

id_employee_department, employee_id, department_id, role ...

---

1, 1, 123123, ROLE_STAFF
2, 1, 123124, ROLE_MANAGER
...

---

John is a staff for the department 123123 at the same time he is a manager for the 123124.

I wrote security-bean property,

```
   <jdbc-user-service id="userService" data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select username, password, true from employee where username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from employee left join employee_department on id_employee = employee_id where username=?"/>
```

The problem is,

John has ROLE_STAFF, ROLE_MANAGER both always. It means He can access all data of the 123123 department and sees useless information for staffs as well when he accesses 123124.

..

What's the best practice to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem as to combine two tables with a new column like {department_id}_{username}

So,

Now, there is only 1 table concerning employee.

```
employee
__
id_employee, username, password, role ...
__
1, 123123_John, woeurewoij12332, ROLE_STAFF ...
2, 123124_John, woeijfskdjfisahf2, ROLE_MANAGER ...
3, 123123_Peter, woieruweoriuo1231, ROLE_STAFF...
___
```

I also seperated Employee entity object and dao service to protect password and role.

Anyway, I solved MY problem. Is there any problem which I couldn't imagine?